# Multiple linear regression with missing covariates

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, missing-data

Imagine I have a dataset like

`df <- data.frame(y=c(11:16), x1=c(23,NA,27,20,20,21), x2=c(NA,9,2,9,7,8))`

```
df
   y x1 x2
1 11 23 NA
2 12 NA  9
3 13 27  2
4 14 20  9
5 15 20  7
6 16 21  8
```

If I perform a multiple linear regression, I get

```
m <- lm(y~x1+x2, data=df)
summary(m)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = df)

Residuals:
         3          4          5          6 
-1.744e-01 -1.047e+00 -4.233e-16  1.221e+00 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 19.72093   27.06244   0.729    0.599
x1          -0.24419    0.93927  -0.260    0.838
x2           0.02326    1.01703   0.023    0.985

Residual standard error: 1.617 on 1 degrees of freedom
  (2 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.4767,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.5698 
F-statistic: 0.4556 on 2 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.7234
```

Here we have 2 observations (1 and 2) deleted due to missingness.

To reduce the effects of missing data, would it be wise to compute 2 different simple linear regressions?

I.e.

```
m1 <- lm(y~x1, data=df)
m2 <- lm(y~x2, data=df)
```

In this case, for each model we will have only 1 observation deleted due to missingness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that would probably not be wise. 
Because you run into the issue of [omitted variables bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias). 
You can see how this will affect your estimates, for instance for `x1`, which is inflated:

```
summary(lm(y~x1, data=df))
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1, data = df)

Residuals:
      1       3       4       5       6 
-2.5287  0.8276 -0.5460  0.4540  1.7931 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  21.3276     7.1901   2.966   0.0592 .
x1           -0.3391     0.3216  -1.054   0.3692  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.897 on 3 degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.2703,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.02713 
F-statistic: 1.112 on 1 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.3692
```

Note that you're relation of interest is `y~x1+x2`, so the effect of `x1` on `y` accounting for the effect of `x2`, and vice versa. 
That is of course not the same as estimating `y~x1` and `y~x2`separately, where you omit the effect of the other explanatory variable.

Now there are of course strategies to deal with missing values. 
One option is estimating a Bayesian model, using `JAGS` for instance, where you can model the missing values. An example would be the following for instance, where I take the mean and standard deviation of each variable to model the missing values:

```
model{
  for(i in 1:N){
    y[i] ~ dnorm(yhat[i], tau)
    yhat[i] <- a+ b1*x1[i] + b2*x2[i]

    # Accounting for missing data
    x1[i]~dnorm(22,3)
    x2[i]~dnorm(7,1.3) 
    }
  # Priors
  b1~dnorm(0, .01)    
  b2~dnorm(0, .01)    

  # Hyperpriors
  tau <- pow(sd, -2)
  sd ~ dunif(0, 20)
}
```

This is just off the top of my head. 
For better and more insightful advice on how deal with missing values I would recommend paying a visit to [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)